# Should the air in a pneumatic tire be included in factors contributing to hysteresis, or should only the tire/tube material be considered?

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science, elasticity

From my understanding the elastomeric properties of a tire with its casing and rubber, and a butyl tube are considered as contributors to hysteresis.  The thicker the tire and tube,the greater the hysteresis, and therefore the greater the energy lost to heat as the material stretches and rebounds.  It seems to me it should be considered separately, since the air contained is a gas and does not behave in an elastic manner.

Comment: The mass of air in the tire is inconsequential, but the air pressure in the tire definitely affects how much hysteresis the tire experiences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more air there is inside the tube and tire, the less the system will flex back and forth as it rolls down the road. Less air means more flexure and therefore more hysteresis losses- and the temperature of the tire goes up.

In fact the easiest way to make a tire fail catastrophically is to underinflate it and then drive fast. The generation rate of hysteresis heat is then high enough to raise the temperature of the tire to the point where the rubber loses its strength and comes apart. A tire which has failed in this way will be hot enough to smoke, and if given a spark, catch on fire.

Note that this is the reason why tire manufacturers recommend putting more air pressure in your tires before starting out on a long high-speed trip, especially on a hot day.

Note also there are special tires made out of heat-resistant rubber that are used on high-performance and racing cars, so that when they are going 200MPH the tires will last longer despite the higher heating they experience.